# How to change the index type of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
```

When I check the `dtype` of the index of the `df` I get the following:

```
In [xx]: df.index.values.dtype
Out[xx]: dtype('int64')
```

How can I change the dtype to `int32` or other data type?

I know that one was it to set one of the columns as `int32` and then use `.set_index` however this does not seem very neat. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: why does this matter? Also note that you're calling `.values` so this converts the default index to a numpy array, the default index is a `RangeIndex`

Comment: Nope you can not

Comment: Wen in this case, what is the best way to do it?
@EdChum it matters because I would like to have control over the idex types.

Comment: But you can't override it, so there is no best way

Comment: As EdChum points out you do **not** want to convert `RangeIndex` to `Int32`. But if you can't be convinced of this, see the duplicate.